# Hover not working in css

Tags: html, css

I'm here to ask a question I know is simple, but I just can not get it to work. I want to change the background color of my li tag to a different color once a user hovers over it.

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;

    text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #aaa;
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #000;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an a to the hover and it works

```css
nav {
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;

    text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #aaa;
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: sorry I tried to put this as the answer but clicked something else. Thank you this really help me

Comment: Dang sorry. Is there anyway I could fix that?

Comment: @Scope: You actually flagged it as spam. No harm done since it was clearly an accident.

Comment: @Michael Myers Thanks

Comment: Thanks Scope and @Micheal Myers, and by the way to get the newest Samsung HD tv and a special low price CLICK HERE

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that there are links inside the li tags - `<a>` tags. Those take on their own color when hovering. So you'll have to define your desired color for `li a:hover { color: ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Your styling for the anchor tag is interfering with your `li:hover` instructions.

You have to think of them as layers, especially when you're using them as block elements. The dimensions of the anchor tag are bigger than the ones of the li tag, hence you don't see the hover effect. I corrected your code. This works:

```
nav {
background-color: #333;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
}
nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: #333;
}
nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #666;
color: #000;
}
nav ul li a {
color: #aaa;
background: transparent;
display: block;
line-height: 2em;
padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Try to see, if you notice what I changed. This helps you to understand what was wrong in the first place. :)

Comment: nav ul li has a background of #333

Comment: Yes and the links have a transparent background. Because you wanted the hover effect to be bound to the list items, not to the anchor tags, as you now do because you marked another answer as correct one. The solution I provided is only a little different from the other one but sticks to what you presented to us in the first place. I have not changed your logic, but only help you correct a mistake. The answer you marked as correct changed your logic. :)

Comment: Is one way better then the other, or does it have any advantages?

Comment: Both provide you with a working result right now, but there might be more complex layouts you want to design. That's why I also rearranged your css. So that you might see that `nav ul li(:hover)` is one layer beneath `nav ul li a`. You first wanted list elements to hover, but the anchor tag was above them. That's why I made anchors transparent and put the hover color to the list element tag. If you recognize the layers you are more likely to find the mistakes in the future. :)